# Unable to view details of modified by on Custom List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, custom-lists

As mentioned in the title above, I've added Created by and Modified by column field in my custom list.
But however, when i added a new item into the list, I was not able to see my name  or the person's name, that creates the item.
Would like to know what are the possible reasons to this issue.

UPDATES: 
Here is the [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orNAI.png) i'm facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you dont need to add CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate columns to lists these are added by default.

All you have to do is to edit the default view and add the columns to the default view, if you have a custom view edit it and add the columns.

When you add a column you get the option to add it to default view.

Doing the above will show the columns in the view.

How to change the view
Goto List Settings (Gear icon on right if O365 or Top Ribbon Menu)
On the bottom you will find the "Views" section
Click the "All Items" now you can see all the available columns the Created and CreatedBy will be there just tick it and remove your columns. 
Press ok your columns will be displayed in the view with correct values.

Comment: Hmm, i do need a column that i want to keep track of who added new item to the custom list.
I have updated my issue in my question description box.

Comment: Same answer you dont need to add these columns as its available out of the box, just update your view :)

Comment: I've updated the answer with steps on editing the view just try it

Comment: Hey yes! I've got it. Thank you for that.!